# Where are the the pi_bcm2835 and spidev files? Is "/etc/modules.load.ed" the same as "/etc/modules"?

Tags: pi-4, video

- Using a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspberry Pi OS I'm trying to flash Skulls BIOS onto a Lenovo Thinkpad T440p using [this guide](https://github.com/merge/skulls/blob/master/t440p/README.md#first-time-installation) and one of the steps states "For flashrom we put `pi_bcm2835` and `spidev` in `/etc/modules`".  Where can I find the `pi_bcm2835` and `spidev` files?
- Also, in `/etc/` I only see a folder named something like `/modules.load.ed`. Is this the same folder and if not, where do I paste `pi_bcm2835` and `spidev`?
- Should I copy or cut `pi_bcm2835` and `spidev` to the modules folder?

Comment: This is an old [C library for Broadcom BCM 2835](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/bcm2835/index.html) (which is little used, although it claims to support Pi4). You need to compile & install it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

/etc/modules is a file, not a directory.

You literally put "spi_bcm2835" and "spidev" on separate lines without the quotes in the file so it looks something like this

[image]

**Source: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2119724#p2119724.**

Comment: You can select your answer as the correct one if it solved your problem. Doing so will help others who may run into the same problem.